# How to create a page with 4x10 grid and print it out

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I am creating a WinForm application that basically generates Math worksheets. I know there are few of them out there already but most are paid and the free ones do not have the options I want.

Anyway, the point of the app is to create a "page" in a 4 x 10 grid (this can be changed to 5x8, 2x20, etc.) where each cell would contain a Math problem. Think of an address label sheet.

My questions:

1. Do I create a form exactly the way I want it and then print out the form? If so, that would be 5 labels per question or 200 labels per sheet. Kind of cumbersome, IMO.
2. Is there a way to create a one template with 5 labels, populate the text property of the 5 labels and then "rubberstamp" the template 40 times per page in a 4x10 for example? This method would be preferable since then I don't have to generate the math problems and keep track of what numbers will go to what label.

I apologize if the title is little confusing but I could not think of a better one.

Thanks

Comment: From my point of view you should use Latex for doing this. If you want to generate something you could gerenate the Latex sources. Anyway, when dealing with printing your best bet is a reporting engine like Crystal Reports or Telerik Reporting.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do not know anything about LaTex but I will read up on it. As far as reporting engine goes, refer to my comment to Servy' post. Is that what you are talking about? –

Comment: No, reporting engines are used to generate sheets with informations. That can be letters you'r sending to your clients as well as math worksheets for your students. You usually create a template (your grid for instance) and add data/content to that templates. But really, every (math) worksheets I have seen in my live were did with Latex and it's great for creating any type of (scientific) document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for user controls.  Create a user control that represents one problem, with all of the labels/formatting/whatever for that one question.  Your worksheet can then add a number of those user controls to the form.  (I'd do this dynamically using for loops rather than dragging 40 of them onto a form, especially if the number isn't static.)

Comment: Just to be clear, I would:
1. Create a user control representing 1 problem
2. dynamically add the user controls based on my needs
3. click on a print button my form which will then print the form?

Assuming my steps above are correct, how do I know how many user controls will fit on a printed page besides printing out pages to get the number of user controls right? Or would it be better to do the steps above and then use a reporting engine to generate the page to be printed?

Comment: I haven't done much with printing myself, but I would imagine that you could figure out how many problems fit on a given page (if you ensure that the size of the user control is static) and then gather up your problems into groups of that many.